# How can I create a slider to change a color?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Essentially, I am trying to take a value, defined by a slider on the interface, pass that value through an array to choose a colour, and pass that color through to a function containing a fill.style.

I have a rough idea to have a go about this, but it isn't working at this stage.

to start with, I have created a slider in my html:

```
 <p id="attribute">Color Slider</p> 
 <span id="sliderColor">2</span>
 <input type="range" min="0" max="3" value="2" step="1" onchange="sliderChangeColor(this.value)"/>
         <br /> <br />
```

I have no idea where to start with this color function. I'd imagine it would be something like...

```
   var colourChange = [(132,0,0), (132,0,132), (189,189,0)];
```

laying 3 different colours out in an array

```
  function sliderColorChange (value) {
                document.getElementById('sliderHeight').innerHTML = value;
                flakeColor = +value;   // + will convert the string to number
            }
        }
```

passing the slider value through to the fill.Style

```
function blank() {
            bufferCanvasCtx.fillStyle = colorChange;
        }
```

This is probably completely wrong at this stage, so any help in form of a solution or a link to a resource which may be of use would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xGAJ8/ this would worth inpsecting

```
<div id="mydiv"  style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;"></div></br>
<div style="background-color:black;color:white;display:inline-block;background-color:red;">
red:<input type="range" min="0" max="255"  value="0" step="1" onChange="changeColor(this.value, 0);"></br>
green:<input type="range" min="0" max="255"  value="0" step="1" onChange="changeColor(this.value, 1);"></br>
blue:<input type="range" min="0" max="255"  value="0" step="1" onChange="changeColor(this.value, 2);"></br>
alpha:<input type="range" min="0" max="1"  value="0" step="0.01" onChange="changeColor(this.value, 3);"></br>
</div>
```

and the js

```
var red=0;
var green=0;
var blue=0;
var alpha=0;
var m = document.getElementById("mydiv");
function changeColor(val,color){
    switch (color) {
        case 0: red = val; break;
        case 1: green = val; break;
        case 2: blue = val; break;
        case 3: alpha = val; break;
    }    m.style.backgroundColor='rgba('+red+','+green+','+blue+','+alpha+')';
}
```

this can be changed to your needs. just make a function where you have the selector and the array of colours and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be closed of as too broad, but there is a LOTS of things you should check in your code:

```
[(132,0,0), (132,0,132), (189,189,0)];
```

Not sure what you want to achieve with the round brackets, you probably want to replace them using square brackets.

```
bufferCanvasCtx.fillStyle = colorChange;
```

`colorChange` instead of `colourChange`? And `fillStyle` should be a string, not an array. And you aren't selecting the specific value you selected. And it only defines what background color the next thing you draw on the canvas will be.